# how to make make separate 1D arrays from containing elements as rows of 2D arrays in java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, split

i want to make separate 1D arrays as row vectors of a n X n matrix taken as a two dimensional array a[n][n]. How to do that in Java ???

What i am trying to do is i have a two dimensional array whose size is nXn where n is specified at run-time and i want to arrange all the row elements in ascending order.Then i cant find any possible way of doing that. Because of that I thought that i will have to separate the row elements and store them separately in another array. But how do i create a new array inside for loop everytime so that the created array stores the row elements. Can you suggest that. Or could you suggest any other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An *n* x *n* matrix is *already* an array of *n* 1D arrays each containing *n* elements. Consider the following 3x3 array:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[][] {
    new int[] { 1, 2, 3 },
    new int[] { 4, 5, 6 },
    new int[] { 7, 8, 9 }
};
```

You can sort each row of such a matrix pretty easily:

```
public static <T> void sortMaxtrixRows(T[][] mat) { sortMatrixRows(mat, null); }

public static <T> void sortMatrixRows(T[][] mat, Comparator<? super T> comp) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        Arrays.sort(mat[i], comp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get completely your question, but from what I think you want is to have each row of the 2d array in a 1d array. If that's the case you can have a 1d array of size = the number of rows in your 2d array. Each entry in the 1d array contains another array which has the size = the number of column in the 2d array. However, if possible you should just try to extract the data from the 2d array directly if possible, so that you don't have to represent a new data structure which essentially contains the same data.

Answer (score 0):

```
int [] ONE_D_ARAAY[]=new int[n*n];
int [][] TWO_D_ARRAY=new int[n][n];
int index=0;
for(int x=0; x<n ;++n)
  for(int y=0; y<n ++y)
     ONE_D_ARRAY[index++]=TWO_D_ARRAY[x][y];
```

Comment: that won't work for me as i want to take only the row elements as separate. I want all the row elements as separate so that i can arrange all the row elements in ascending order. By doing what you have mentioned above if afterwards i apply any sort algorithm then that will arrange all the elements of the 2d array in ascending order not the row elements separately